# Compare performance of the SVM with and without stochastic gradient descent

Tags: python, svm, gradient-descent

I'd like to compare the performance of the SVM classifier with and without the stochastic gradient descent. In the sklearn I've only found the SGDClassifier (that I can put into a pipeline). 
Doesn't sklearn provide an implementation of a non-stochastic (batch) gradient descent classifier? Do I have to implement both classifiers on my own in order to conduct an analysis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**When SVMs and SGD can't be combined**

SVMs are often used in combination with the kernel trick, which enables classification of non-linearly separable data. This answer explains why you wouldn't use stochastic gradient descent to solve a kernelised SVM: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215524/is-gradient-descent-possible-for-kernelized-svms-if-so-why-do-people-use-quadr

**Linear SVMs**

If we stick to Linear SVMs, then we can run an experiment using `sklearn`, as it provides wrappers over [`libsvm`](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) ([`SVC`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)), [`liblinear`](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) ([`LinearSVC`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC)) and also offers the [`SGDClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html). Recommend reading the linked documentation of `libsvm` and `liblinear` to understand what is happening under the hood.

**Comparison on example dataset**

Below is a comparison of computational performance and accuracy over a randomly generated dataset (which may not be representative of your problem). You should alter the problem to fit your requirements.

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Randomly generated dataset
# Linear function + noise
np.random.seed(0)
X = np.random.normal(size=(50000, 10))
coefs = np.random.normal(size=10)
epsilon = np.random.normal(size=50000)
y = (X @ coefs + epsilon) > 0

# Classifiers to compare
algos = {
    'LibSVM': {
        'model': SVC(),
        'max_n': 4000,
        'time': [],
        'error': []
    },
    'LibLinear': {
        'model': LinearSVC(dual=False),
        'max_n': np.inf,
        'time': [],
        'error': []
    },
    'SGD': {
        'model': SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000, tol=1e-3),
        'max_n': np.inf,
        'time': [],
        'error': []
    }
}

splits = list(range(100, 1000, 100)) + \
         list(range(1500, 5000, 500)) + \
         list(range(6000, 50000, 1000))
for i in splits:
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                        test_size=1-i/50000,
                                                        random_state=0)
    for k, v in algos.items():
        if i < v['max_n']:
            model = v['model']
            t0 = time.time()
            model.fit(X_train, y_train)
            t1 = time.time()
            v['time'].append(t1 - t0)
            preds = model.predict(X_test)
            e = (preds != y_test).sum() / len(y_test)
            v['error'].append(e)
```

Plotting the results, we see that the traditional libsvm solver cannot be used on large n, while the liblinear and SGD implementations scale well computationally.

```
plt.figure()
for k, v in algos.items():
    plt.plot(splits[:len(v['time'])], v['time'], label='{} time'.format(k))
plt.legend()
plt.semilogx()
plt.title('Time comparison')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Plotting the error, we see that SGD is worse than LibSVM for the same training set, but if you have a large training set this becomes a minor point. The `liblinear` algorithm performs best on this dataset:

```
plt.figure()
for k, v in algos.items():
    plt.plot(splits[:len(v['error'])], v['error'], label='{} error'.format(k))
plt.legend()
plt.semilogx()
plt.title('Error comparison')
plt.xlabel('Number of training examples')
plt.ylabel('Error')
plt.show()
```

[image]